# How to compute and display 50% of total once partial payment is selected using (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form like this:

```
<?php
//Example of total
 $total = "100.00";

?>

<form>
<select name="payment">
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="Full Payment">Full Payment</option>
<option value="Partial Payment">Partial Payment</option>
</select>

//Display amount to be payed here.(Echo in text)

Amount:
</input type="text" name="amount">
</form>
```

Once full payment is selected, display total amount to be payed here.
If partial payment is selected, display total amount to be payed in 50%

Comment: You need to store `$total` in `data-*` attribute and use it.

Comment: i dont get what you mean sir.. you mean stroring the $total variable into form and setting type to hidden.. But how to call this using javascript and by means you compute it and to be displayed it once Partial payment is selected.

So i have to add onchange event on form select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML page needs to have the total in somewhere in order for JavaScript to be able to access it. You can store it in a hidden input field. You can then perform the calculation and put the value into the output text box.

```
<?php
//Example of total
$total = "100.00";
?>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="total_payment" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" />
    <select name="payment">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
        <!-- you can add new options with different percentages with data-percentage -->
        <option data-percentage="100" value="Full Payment">Full Payment</option>
        <option data-percentage="50" value="Partial Payment">Partial Payment</option>
    </select>

    Amount: <span id="calculated_price"></span>
</form>

<script>
    function onChangePaymentAmount() {
        // the <select>
        var select = document.querySelector("[name='payment']");

        // the <option> which has been chosen
        var selected_option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

        // the selected percentage
        var percentage = selected_option.dataset["percentage"];

        // the total cost (here taken from the hidden input)
        var price = document.querySelector("[name='total_payment']").value;

        // the element which will have the output
        var output = document.getElementById("calculated_price");

        var calculated_price;

        // update the output
        if (percentage) {
            calculated_price = price * percentage / 100;
        } else {
            calculated_price = price;
        }
        output.innerHTML = calculated_price.toFixed(2);
    }

    // add an event listener for when the <select> changes
    document.querySelector("[name='payment']").addEventListener("change", onChangePaymentAmount, false);

    // optionally run the function on page load to populate the percentage
    // onChangePaymentAmount();
</script>
```

Comment: sir i gotta add an onchange attribute on my select form? like this:
<select name="payment" onchange="onChangePaymentAmount()">

Comment: Nope. `document.querySelector("[name='payment']").addEventListener(...)` at the bottom of the script adds the event for you.

Comment: sir i think you forgot to put the display for <span id="amount_chosen_to_pay"></span>

Comment: @Adrian I misunderstood the question before, the `<span>` was a mistake, I noticed that you have a textbox for output, so I used that in the answer.

Comment: its alright sir.. all i want is to have a display for the cashier to let him know that the partial payment to be payed is ____. So that the cashier will no need to calculate the percentage using a calculator. 

Sir can you display the output of data in money format?.. like 50.00

Comment: Instead to display it on the textbox, can you display it on your span sir? or just display it on <p></p> or <label></label>.. Thank you very much

Comment: @Adrian updated to use a span and added `.toFixed(2)` for formatting.

Comment: Sir.. can you add some codes that i have requested on the comments i entered.

Comment: It works..Thank you vry much. Good job :D.. gonna vote for this.. Thnx

Comment: One last request sir. How can i add a string on the output? like: "Amount to be payed is $____"

Comment: -->One last request sir. How can i add a string on the output? like: "Amount to be payed is $____"

Comment: @Adrian I can think of at least three ways to do this. I'm sure you can too :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php
//Example of total
$total = "100.00";

//add this IF else statement 
if($_GET['payment']=="Full Payment"){
    $amount=$total;
}
elseif($_GET['payment']=="Partial Payment"){
    $amount= $total*0.50;
}
else{
    $amount="";
}
?>

<form>
<select name="payment">
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="Full Payment">Full Payment</option>
<option value="Partial Payment">Partial Payment</option>
</select>

//Display amount to be payed here.(Echo in text)

Amount:
<input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount;?>">
 <!-- also add echo the value in textbox  -->

 <!--I added check button to submit -->
 <button>Check Amount</button>

 </form>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: This code is vulnerable to XSS. You should *always* distrust user input and escape it.